# How to get data from XML feed URL in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

There is a betting exchange website which offer their data in XML from the following link:

http://odds.smarkets.com/oddsfeed.xml

I would like to access this link to retrieve the latest data (in java).  Previously I have had to download the (very large) file and add it to my project and get the data from there.  What is the best way to achieve this without having to download the file every time I want to access the data?

I plan on storing the returned data into a database.

Thanks

Comment: hi Rossc you need to create a web service application  to hit this url and get the contents from this url. You can use REST to call this url.But what contents you need to read depends on the functionality that you need to achieve.You need to write your custom logic to read the data.Here in you will be client and the url would be your service

Comment: Hello Rossc,Hope my answer helped you .If yes please accept the answer if not please let me know so that I can improvise on that and help you to give  a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to be very tricky question .I would suggest  you  to create a simple  `web service` application`[Client/server architecture]`  to get the contents from this url. You can use `REST` to call this url. But what contents you need to read depends on the functionality that you want to achieve.You need to write your custom logic to read the data.Here in you will be acting as client and the url would be your service.

You can refer following link

> https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Access-page-content-via-URL/qaq-p/163060